# Tomcat server SSL enabled necessary?

Tags: tomcat, ssl, certificate

I have a question in regards to enabling ssl on Tomcat (web container).

Here is the scenario I have.

There is a web app deployed to the web container and this app sends http get/post request to an external system (service provider). The service provider's uri scheme is "https". The service provider presents its server certificate issued by an intermediate ca which in turn issued by root ca.

Unless I add intermediate/root certificates into $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts in the machine where the web container is installed/running. I get an exception (I believe ssl hand shake exception..) when http get/post request is fired.

I thought Tomcat (web container) needs to be ssl enabled in order to communicate with ssl enabled server. However request-response cycle was successful without enabling the client (Tomcat).

Can someone help me to better understand this situation? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling SSL in Tomcat enables clients to connect *to Tomcat* via HTTPS. It has nothing to do with Tomcat making outbound connections *to something else.*